# How to start dashing under Supervisord

Tags: linux, supervisord, dashing

I'm trying to run my dashing (dashing.io) dashboard under Supervisord but can't seem to get it working properly.

The message Supervisor gives me is "Process exited to quickly".

I'm doing the following in my supervisord.conf:

```
[program:dashing]
directory = my directory goes here
command= dashing start &
process_name=dashing
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=QUIT
stdout_logfile = /var/log/dashing/dashing.log
```

Any help would be appriciated in getting this running.  For information the dashing server works if I do dashing start myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I have Supervisord successfully running dashing persisting through reboots.
(See Bottom for [program:dashing])

```
colin@mikrodash:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I installed with the standard method:

```
colin@mikrodash:~$ sudo apt-get update
colin@mikrodash:~$ sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

My conf files are as follows:

```
colin@mikrodash:~$ sudo cat /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf 
; supervisor config file
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)
chmod=0700                       ; sockef file mode (default 0700)
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)
; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket
; The [include] section can just contain the "files" setting.  This
; setting can list multiple files (separated by whitespace or
; newlines).  It can also contain wildcards.  The filenames are
; interpreted as relative to this file.  Included files *cannot*
; include files themselves.
[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf

colin@mikrodash:~$ sudo cat /etc/supervisor/conf.d/dashing.conf
[program:dashing]
command=dashing start -p 3030 -e production
directory=/opt/dashing/rmm_hud
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stdout_logfile=/opt/dashing/rmm_hud/logs/dashing.log
redirect_stderr=true
stopsignal=QUIT
```